# Deriving the Hamiltonian for a simple pendulum using mechanical momentum as a free parameter

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

So when we covered the derivation of  a simple pendulum we , and from what ive found on the web, defined our free parameter as $q=L\theta$ and arrive at the Hamiltonian for a Harmonic oscillator.

But we were also told that this is an arbitrary choice and that any other available parameter would work, such as momentum.

So now trying to use the momentum of the pendulum as my free parameter but it is turning out to be less trivial than the lecturer seemd to imply.

[image]

So i begin with setting  $q=mv=m\dot{\theta}$ and then i dont know how to proceed. When trying to get the lagrangian i first try to find the potential energy $V(q)=\frac{1}{2}mgh=\frac{1}{2}mgL(1-cos(\theta))$

Now with theta as the free parameter we just approximated $\frac{1}{2}mgL(1-cos(\theta))=\frac{1}{2}mgL\theta=mgq$ but now when im trying to do the same thing , rewrite the potential energy as a function of $q$ im getting nowhere.

How am i supposed to do this? Its annoying me quite abit since this was supposed to be a trivial process so  it seems like i am lacking some understanding of the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to obtain the kinetic and potential energy you start with the position vector to the mass point which is:

$$\vec{R}=l\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin(\varphi) \\
  -\cos(\varphi) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\varphi$ is the generalized coordinate, but you can choose other

generalized coordinate $q=l\,\varphi~,\Rightarrow~ \varphi=\frac{q}{l}$
your position vector is now :

$$\vec{R}=l\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin(\frac{q}{l}) \\
  -\cos(\frac{q}{l}) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

from hear the kinetic energy is

$$T=\frac m2(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)=\frac m2\,\dot{q}^2$$

the potential energy is:

$$U=m\,g\,h=-m\,\,g\,l\,\cos(\frac{q}{l})$$

thus the total energy is $E=T+U$

the Hamiltonian for conservative system is the total energy

$$H=E=\frac 12\,m{{\dot q}}^{2}-m\,g\,l\cos \left( {\frac {q}{l}} \right)  
$$

with  $p=m\,\dot{q}$ you obtain:

$$H=\frac 12\,\frac{{p^2}}{m}-m\,g\,l\cos \left( {\frac {q}{l}} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first be clear about the base.

A classical physical system is described by a set of canonical coordinates $r = (q, p)$, where each component of the coordinate $q_i$, $p_i$ is indexed to the frame of reference of the system. The $q_i$ are called generalized coordinates, and $p_i$ are their conjugate momenta.

$$\dot{q}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial p}, \ \ \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ \ \dot{p}=-\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial q} $$
where $\mathcal{H}(q,p,t)$ is Hamiltonian of system. For a closed system, it is the sum of the kinetic and potential energy in the system.

---

> So when we covered the derivation of a simple pendulum we , and from what ive found on the web, defined our free parameter as $q=Lθ$ and arrive at the Hamiltonian for a Harmonic oscillator.

As we have defined the Hamiltonian is function of generalized coordinate and their conjugate momenta. So it's not possible to choose just $q$ to solve the problem with the help of Hamiltonian's equation. Conjugate momenta can be found as
$$p=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}$$

Rest of your doubts are  associated with this.

Note that you are independent to choose generalized coordinate. You can construct Lagrangian in that coordinate and then find out the Hamiltonian for such coordinate and then can use to find equation of motion. The standard formula related to this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) or any text on classical Mechanics.

Comment: But to get a conjugate momenta i first need the Lagrangian which depends on my choice of $q$. The thing i dont get is how im supposed to write the Lagrangian if i choose q to be the mechanical momentum of the pendulum

Comment: You can not take the mechanical momenta to write Lagrangian. It's coordinate.

Comment: Thats wierd. Pretty sure our lecturer said you can.  Maybe i misheard. Why cant you do that if i might ask?

Comment: Generalize coordinate are used describe the position of particle in configuration space, you can do that with momenta. For example you can do the problem in caretesian or polar coordinates or any other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates You might wanna look on this and On lagrangian too.

Comment: You can use the momenta and one of independent coordinate in phase space to do that you need to choose the genralize coordinate associated with that momenta. But generalize coordinate will also be one of the coordinate. means $q,p$ in Hamiltonian.

Comment: Alright, thanks!.